# How to create a custom Swing Document structure

Tags: java, swing, document, jeditorpane, javax.swing.text

I have a `JEditorPane` holding a custom `EditorKit` and a custom `Document` (derived from DefaultStyledDocument).

The following is an example for the content of the `JEditorPane`:

---

first **paragraph**

second paragraph

---

For the example above I get a document-structure with the following XML-equivalent:

```html
<root>
    <section>

        <paragraph>
            <content>first</content>
            <content bold="true">paragraph</content>
        </paragraph>

        <paragraph>
            <content>second paragraph</content>
            <content>\n</content>
        </paragraph>

    </section>
</root>
```

*Note that the tag names above are determined by the Element.getName() function.*

**My intention is, to extend this structure by custom element types to edit content other than styled text.**

An example would be extending the editor to be a music-note editor to get an XML-structure like this:

```html
<root>
    <section>

        <paragraph>
            <content>first</content>
            <content bold="true">paragraph</content>
        </paragraph>

        <musicnotes>
            <bar>
                <note>C</note>
                <note>D</note>
                <note>E</note>
            </bar>
        </musicnotes>

    </section>
</root>
```

As I see it, the Style- and Paragraph-Elements are created upon Document.insertString() and Document.setCharacterAttributes() methods.

My problem is that I have no clue how to override these methods (or write pendants) to not to go back to the default structure but to use custom element kinds.

At all I don't even know if this is the correct approach. Do I have to create my very own Implementation of the Document-interface to create a custom document structure?

Comment: I tried this a while back and yes, you need to write a whole document structure, implementing all parts of the tree. The documentation for this isn't great, and it will take you a while.

Comment: It is possible just by deriving DefaultStyledDocument. The accepted answer contains an interesting link. `Document.insert(int offset, ElementSpec[] spec)` is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example of tables creation.
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTables.html

You can use the same defining desired structure.